# Custom views folder with resharper IntelliSense

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, intellisense

Can I setup view storage folder location (or to be more specific: storage convention, e.g. each project: /Bindings/Views) so that Resharper would know where to find them and display correct validations? Right now by moving views we lost resharper support for navigating to views and getting feedback abut missing views.

Comment: Do you mean Razor views? Or what kind of views?

Comment: Razor views and asp mvc 4 application

Answer (score 2):

How do you change location? ReSharper understands assigning of  ViewLocationFormats & others view properties of ViewEngine.